# Keep EasyAutocomplete but remove Browser autocomplete

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using jQuery's [EasyAutocomplete](http://easyautocomplete.com/) .. the problem is that when I click on the text field my browser triggers it's own auto complete which looks really ugly together with the other one. `autocomplete="off"` doesn't seem to do anything .. both autocompletes work. Is there any way I can see only the desired autocomplete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try these:

1. Add autocomplete="off" onto  element;
2. Add hidden  with autocomplete="off" as a first children element of the form.

```html
<form autocomplete="off" method="post" action="">
        <input autocomplete="off" name="hidden" type="text" style="display:none;">
</form>
```

But many modern browsers do not support `autocomplete="off"` for login fields. You should use `autocomplete="new-password"` for new password fields (can be used in login fields) in order for it to not be auto filled.

I hope it would work for you